How do I go about making my popup element appear over the publications page, similar to how google scholar’s cite button popup works?
I was working on a publications page and wanted to have the bibtex be a popup, kind of like how google scholar’s cite button works (NOT their bibtex button which links to a new page).
The issue is that I can’t get the popup to overlay on top of the page. I’ve tried moving the popup out of the  block, or out of the div element, even into a new file and then importing to Publications.js, but none of it works.
It is true that this moves around the popup (either above/below the p section or the entire main section) but it doesn’t make it get on top of everything else like the google scholars version does. I think perhaps this is due to how my container is defined? Also, I already tried things like adjusting the top, bottom, etc., and changing the z value.
Here is my code below, for the publications main section js and cs files, publications.js, popup.js and popup.css.
Google Scholars Popup
My popup
PublicationsMain.js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Popup from './pages/Popup';
import './PublicationsMain.css';

function PublicationsMain() {
  const [firstButtonPopup, setFirstButtonPopup]=useState(false);
  return (

<> <div className='publications-main-container'>
      <p className="firstp">random text[
            <button onClick={()=>setFirstButtonPopup(true)}>bibtex</button>] 
              <Popup trigger={firstButtonPopup} setTrigger={setFirstButtonPopup}>
              <h3>bibtex</h3>
              <p>Here is my bibtex</p>
              </Popup>
              </p>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default PublicationsMain;

PublicationsMain.css
 :root {
    --font-size: 31px;
}

.publications-main-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    object-fit: contain;
}


.publications-main-container > p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 
    'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3rem;
}

.publications-main-container > p.firstp {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.publications-main-container > p.secondp {
    background-color: #2e557f;
}

.publications-main-container > p.thirdp {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.publications-main-container > p.fourthp {
    background-color: #2e557f;
}

.publications-main-container > p > span {
    color: #fff;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 
    'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.publications-main-container > p > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 
    'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}


.publications-main-container > p > button {
    background: none!important;
    border: none;
    padding: 0!important;
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 
    'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}

Popup {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000000000;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 1093px) {
    /* .publications-main-container > h1 {
        font-size: 80px;
    } */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 978px) {
    /* .publications-main-container > h1 {
        font-size: 60px;
    } */
    :root {
        --font-size: 27px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 784px) {
    /* .publications-main-container > h1 {
        font-size: 55px;
    } */

    :root {
        --font-size: 23px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 701px) {
    /* .publications-main-container > h1 {
        font-size: 47px;
    } */
}

Publications.js
import PublicationsHero from '../PublicationsHero';
import PublicationsMain from '../PublicationsMain';

function Publications() {
  return (
    <>
      <PublicationsHero />
      <PublicationsMain />
    </>
  );
}

export default Publications;

Popup.js
import React from 'react'
import './Popup.css';

function Popup(props) {
  return (props.trigger) ? (
    <div className="Popup">
        <div className="popup-inner">
            <button className="close-btn" onClick={()=>props.setTrigger(false)}>&#x2715; 
            &#x00d7; </button>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    </div>
  ) : "";
}

export default Popup;

Popup.css
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.popup-inner{
    position:relative;
    padding:32px;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.popup-inner .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top:16px;
    right:16px;
}

Edit: I have a feeling I need to find a method to make the popup overpass/exit all containers, but I am unsure how to go about this (I had already tried things like z value adjustments to no avail/difference). I also tried moving it around the html file but that didn’t move it out of the container, just below it (or above depending on where exactly I moved it in the html). I had also tried making a separate popup file to import the popup but that did the same as just moving it around in the html, not to mention complicating it even more with the button clicks.
